# Errors on startup

Tags: debian, boot, lxqt, smbclient, rc.local

I have installed 3 days ago Debian 10.3.0 with LXQT.
It's great and I like it, it boot fine, each kernel line on boot is so great to see when appears 2 red lines that are so ugly!

```
[OK] Started /etc/rc.local.
[26.409377] CIFS: Unknown mount option "umask=000"
[FAILED] Failed to mount /mnt/smb.
See 'systemctl status mnt-smb.mount' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
```

I have created rc.local to make ConnMan UI to fix my lan card to work properly. So thanks to rc.local it launch on boot the command to make it work properly. Is the error on boot caused by this change?
Everything works fine, please tell me how to fix this to have a 100% clean boot.
Also, when the system startup reach this line, it slow down the boot of 5 seconds.

The file rc.local contain

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/sbin/ethtool -s ens5f5 speed 100 duplex full

exit 0
```

**Edit #1** This is the output of `systemctl status mnt-smb.mount`

```
systemctl status mnt-smb.mount
● mnt-smb.mount - /mnt/smb
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-30 15:02:35 
    Where: /mnt/smb
     What: //192.168.1.171/ADMIN-PC
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
lines 1-7/7 (END)
```

Infact yes, I have tried to link Windows with Debian via lan without success. Maybe my attempts generated this trouble that I don't know how to fix!

Comment: Did you try `systemctl status mnt-smb.mount` as suggested? Did you configure anything to mount something using CIFS/SMB/SAMBA, e.g. a mount from a Windows system or NAS? Please [edit] your question to add information, don't answer in comments.

Comment: I've just added more information, thanks.

Comment: Problem solved! I removed the last line in the file /etc/fstab, that was the local machine info badly linked.